# How to get value from HTML to Suitescript?

Tags: javascript, html, netsuite

I am writing a suitelet in  suitescript 2.0 which contains an html part. I need to get the value from html form to a variable in suitelet

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType Suitelet
 */
define([ 'N/http', 'N/email', 'N/record' ,'N/runtime'], 

        function(http, email, record,runtime) {     

 function onRequest(context) {
    function sendGetRequest() {

         var param= http.get({
            url : ''
    });
        var html = '<html><body>something: '
                     + something
                     + '<br/>'
                     +'<form method="post">Input  <input type="text" name="something" id="something" value=""/> <input type="submit"/> </form></body></html>'; 
             log.debug({title : 'param', details : param});
      context.response.write(html);
      var something = html.getParameter('something');
      log.debug({title : 'something', details : something});

        }

    sendGetRequest();

}

return {
    onRequest: onRequest
};

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything you get on the Suitelet is on the context object, if you want specific HTML data, you have to use a client script to put it in one of the form fields.